# setState is not updating the array in the state

Tags: reactjs

I have an array in local state and trying to update it as in the codesandbox below. array in the state is not changing. What am I missing?

Thanks

[First example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mqpr575l89)
[Second example](https://codesandbox.io/s/p3wj82q0v7)

Comment: I've tested your code and the state is changing as expected. I don't really see the problem here, can you explain a little more, please?

Comment: It is: https://codesandbox.io/s/p3wj82q0v7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've removed the redundant tag in the title, and also added the link you posted in the comments to the question. Please remember to edit your questions, so that when someone reads it can instantly understand your problem :)

Comment: Thanks Dominik :)